# linking to google analytics in iframe not working

Tags: iframe, google-analytics, autologin

I've been asked to have it possible to open (and auto login to) google analytics within a php website.  I cant find any recent info that suggests its possible to auto login but even just linking to the page within an iframe doesn't appear to work.  the closest I've been is opening www.google.com/analytics but you can't go into login.  Is there any way to do this that one of you might know of?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are protections in the Google Analytics system that avoid people from loading it inside an iframe and using the web interface programmatically.

Have you checked the [API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/)? You should be able to fetch most of the data from GA using it. It's your best bet.

Comment: I had a feeling that was the case.  Yes, I've seen the API so I guess there is a lot of reading ahead of me.  Thanks!